# Transform String to Expression

Tags: string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, expression-construction

I have a variable `postVector` and another called  `CHKpostVector`. Both are global variables.

Only the variable  `postVector` is passed to a function and inside the function I need to modify the varibale `CHKpostVector`. What I'm doing is to use  `ToExpression[StringJoin["CHK", "postVector"]]` to get the value of `CHKpostVector`.

However I'm not able to change this value because if I use `Symbol @@ StringJoin["CHK", "postVector"]` it gives me the name of the variable as a string.

How can I convert the string `"CHKpostVector"` to the variable `CHKpostVector`?

Comment: `ToExpression["CHKpostVector", StandardForm, Function[sym, sym = 2, HoldFirst]]`

Comment: Let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the question is the same but I couldn't find it. Sorry

Comment: No worries. Good luck.